# How to disable node auto-repair

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

How do I disable GKE cluster nodes maintenance auto-repair using terraform? It seems I can't stop the nodes or change the settings of the GKE nodes from GCP console. So I guess I'll have to try it using terraform even if its recreates the cluster.

How does the maintenance happen? I think it migrates all the pods to the secondary node and then restarts the first node correct? But what if there isn't enough resources available for the secondary node to handle all the nodes from primary node? Will GCP create new node?  For example: Primary node has around 110 pods and secondary node has 110 pods. How the maintenance happen if the nodes needs to be restarted?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable node auto-repair by running the following command in the GCP shell:

```
gcloud container node-pools update <pool-name> --cluster <cluster-name> \
--zone compute-zone \
--no-enable-autorepair
```

You will find how to do it using the GCP console in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-repair#console_3) as well.

If you are still facing issues and want to disable node auto-repair using terraform you have to specify in the *argument* `management` if you want to enable `auto-repair`. You can find further details in the [terraform's](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_node_pool) documentation.

Here you can also find how the [node repair process](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-repair#node_repair_process) works:

> If GKE detects that a node requires repair, the node is drained and re-created. GKE waits one hour for the drain to complete. If the drain doesn't complete, the node is shut down and a new node is created.
>
> If multiple nodes require repair, GKE might repair nodes in parallel. GKE balances the number of repairs depending on the size of the cluster and the number of broken nodes. GKE will repair more nodes in parallel on a larger cluster, but fewer nodes as the number of unhealthy nodes grows.
>
> If you disable node auto-repair at any time during the repair process, in- progress repairs are not cancelled and continue for any node currently under repair.